# Javascript code refactoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, exif

I have the following code which is working

```
var exif = function(exifObject) {
    alert(exifObject.Orientation);
}

$(this).fileExif(exif);
```

Problem is, I need the alerted value after `$(this).fileExif(exif)` line.

So I tried doing the following:

```
function getOrientation(exifObject){
    return(exifObject.Orientation);
}
getOrientation($(this).fileExif());
```

It does not work. How could I achieve to have the alerted value after `$(this).fileExif(exif)` line?

**Additional info**

`console.log(exifObject)` returns an Object with an array of attributes, f.e. `Orientation`.

`$(this)` is wrapped in this code:

```
$('body').on('change', '#imgFile', function(event) {
```

so it's an input type file.

Comment: What is the object output of `console.log(exifObject);`. Also can you show us the code wrapping the getOrientation function, so we know what `$(this)` is.

Comment: I think it is not possible, because it seems that your exif() function is called into fileExif() call. But I'm not sure what you want to do, so maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: added additional info above, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `exif`, which is a function, to the `fileExif` function. This is an example of the fact that functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, and in this case `exif` is a "callback" function. That is, when the `fileExif` function is finished, it passes it's result to the `exif` function, which is then called.

In terms of execution, the `alert` will be called after the `fileExif` function. However, if you desperately want the code to be written after the function, you could declare the function as you pass it:

```
$(this).fileExif(function(exifObject) {
    alert(exifObject.Orientation);
});
```

However, this is probably not as clear as the original.

Comment: thanks! So I thought to reuse the exifObject outside of the function, I could just change "alert" to "return" and catch the return value, but that doesn't work...?

Comment: No, you would have to call another function inside the anonymous function that is passed to `fileExif`, and pass `exifObject.Orientation` to that function.

Answer (score 0):

I find only one fileExif plugin for jQuery. [Here it sources](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif/blob/master/jquery.exif.js).
This plugin use native [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/FileReader).
FileReader load file asynchronously. 
You have 2 way. First - modify plugin code and make it sync (bad idea). Write your code with asycn style (best practice).